# Chrome extension: Popup form not functioning: Does not do anything on submit or communicate with my server

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

Problem: Clicking the 'GO' button does not display the var_dump from my php file, it acts as if nothing is clicked.

Expectation: I am expecting the result of the var dump to be placed into my popup window of my Google Chrome Extension, however when click action happens, it acts as if not clicked. (I understand we aren't doing anything with the data other than a vardump of the post)

Other: I have tried to find something on this (I have spent a few hours googling, but I am not an expert in this) but I haven't found an answer that helps me and I'm really just wanting to use the simple form not fancy ajax stuff.

Permissions in the manifest are already set to allow access to my domain:

```
"permissions": [
     "http://www.example.com/*",
     "https://www.example.com/*",
     "http://example.com/*",
     "https://example.com/*",
}
```

Code popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title>Extension Popup</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mainPopup {
            padding: 10px;
            height: 235px;
            width: 450px;
            font-family: Helvetica, Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 2em;
        }

        input[type="text"] {
            align: center;
            width: 350px;
            padding: 3px;
            margin: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        input[type="submit"] {
            background: orange;
            width: 150px;
            border: 0;
            padding: 10px 35px;
            display: block;
            margin: 5px;
        }


    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <center>
    <div id="mainPopup">
        <h1>Welcome to the My Extension</h1>
        <p>All we need is your name and a valid email and you will will be up and running!<br> Don't worry! We promise not to spam you!</p>
        <form action="http://www.example.com/extension/emailCollect.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
        </form>
    </div>
</center>
</body>
```

Content of emailCollect.php is simple: `<?php>var_dump($_POST);<?>`